# Implementation of articulate

Tags: adapter, articulate

I am looking at Articulate to support my own application. I want my users to be able to use Articulate to create the E-learning and then uploading the files to my site and run it on my site.

However i wish to store both the questions and the answers of the quiz that is created in articulate.

Does anyone know how this is possible or know a way around either by using excel or any other software to store the Q/A?

Answer (score 1):

There may be more than one answer. But Articulate is SCORM compliant. It is designed to return test scores to the server using SCORM. I have not been involved with receiving those test scores by acting as an LMS, but in the past I have made custom applications that send that data to the LMS using scorm. But if you research SCORM and other APIs they use you might find something useful.

For example, if you mean Articulate Storyline then you can test send/receiving data using this package:

http://www.articulate.com/support/storyline/how-to-use-the-scorm-test-suite

This shows that it can be done. But you would have to write your own program to communicate with Storyline. If you can duplicate how that package works you might be on your way.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to SCORM, you can also use the xAPI see https://xapi.com/overview/ to store your e-learning data